# Regex PHP: get specific content from another website

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm writing a PHP script that will fetch specific codes from the other site.

All is done and its fetching a div which has a class and showing it on my page.

```
$title = '#\<div class="detailBox"\>(.+?)\<\/div\>#s';
preg_match($title, $page, $titles);
echo $titles[0];
```

But when I try to fetch  from a table it shows nothing

The content on the other site is like this:

```
<tr>
   <th scope="row">開催時間</th>
   <td>10:30～17:00</td>
</tr>
```

And I'm using this code to fetch it:

```
$date = '#\<tr\><th scope="row"\>開催時間<\/th\><td\>(.+?)\<\/td\><\/tr\>#s';
preg_match($date, $page, $dates);
echo $dates[0];
```

I have tried `$date = '#\<th scope="row"\>開催時間<\/th\>#s';` and it works but not if I add `<td>` in it.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why my question has -2 minus points. I think my question is proper and to the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to turn on the unicode modifier `u` and also match the inbetween line breaks.

```
$date = '#<tr>\s*<th scope="row">開催時間</th>\s*<td>(.+?)</td>\s*</tr>#su';
preg_match($date, $page, $dates);
```

Comment: Thanks Avinash :) ... What if there are more than one tr? ... Should I use preg_match_all() then?

Answer (score 1):

and escape the metacharacters
$date = '#\\開催時間\</th>\(.+?)\</td></tr>#s';
preg_match($date, $page, $dates);

Comment: When answering questions on Stack Overflow, they should really be complete answers. If you are adding to someone else's answer, feel free to add your amendment as a comment at the bottom. The sequence that answers appear on the page can change, so if you need to refer to another answer, it is better to refer to the name of the person who posted the original answer.